# imported XML ERROR : DOMDocument::load(): StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: php, xml

Hi i am trying to import XML file but the file have some special characters `< BS`  like this so in that case `load()` function give an error `DOMDocument::load(): StartTag: invalid element name` how can i remove special characters from my XML file using PHP .. and how can it remove before `load()` function because the error retrieving in `load` function

this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Manifests>
  <Manifest>
    <Message-Header>
      <Message-Id>00002</Message-Id>
      <Sender-Company-ID>TEST</Sender-Company-ID>
      <Sender-Company-Name>PACIFIC STARo<CHINAo<    CO.,LTD.</Sender-Company-Name>
      <Sender-User-ID>QAZ</Sender-User-ID>
      <Recv-Company-Id>0003</Recv-Company-Id>
      <Recv-Company-Name>TEST COMPANY</Recv-Company-Name>
      <Creation-Time>20220621 09:05:21</Creation-Time>
    </Message-Header>
  </Manifest>
</Manifests>
```

this is my code

```
 private function importXML($xmlTagName)
    {
        $isAvailable = true;

        $xmlDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $xmlDom->load($this->xmlfileWithPath);

          $checkTagName = $xmlDom->getElementsByTagName($xmlTagName);
          if ($checkTagName->length == 0) {
              $isAvailable = false;
          }
          return $isAvailable;
    }
```

Comment: You should really rather ask whoever is giving this data to you, to _fix_ their output. This is _not_ well-formed XML; and anyone trying to sell it to you as such, is simply a liar.

Comment: You can effectively disable these warnings when using DOMDocument by calling `libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;` before instantiating the DOMDocument instance

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius
yeah but when i use `libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;`  i cant after use getElementsByTagName function it show null values thats why i not used `libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;`

Comment: You're not trying to import an XML file, you're trying to import a non-XML file. You can't use XML tools to process data that isn't XML. There are tools that will try to repair broken XML, but because "broken XML" is such an ill-defined concept, their behaviour is not easily predictable.